# How to add multiple users in to multiple groups in a new users script?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have a script which is making active directory users, and it's working great.

Here a thing, i need that these users will add them self after the creation to

some groups.

So i've figured out that thre is a cmdle `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`

but I don't know how to combine this CmdLet into my script ( i'm on PowerShell abit more the a month)

i've tried to use another foreach statement but it didn't worked

Here is the Code:

```
cls
#get the csv file
$filepath = import-csv "C:\users.csv"

#set the variable for the uers
$newusers = $filepath

#set Passwords for new users 
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "blahblah" -AsPlainText -Force

#start the loop 
foreach ($user in $newusers) {

    #get user information
    $firstname = $user.'First Name'.Trim()
    $lastname = $user.'Last Name'.Trim()
    $loginname= $user.SamAccountName
    $UsrPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
    $jobtitle = $user.'Job Title'
    $Department= $user.Department
    $Description = $user.Description
    $OuPath= $user.Path
    $LoginScript=$user.ScriptPath
    $displayname= $user.DisplayName

    #create the users in active directory
    $vars = @{
        Name = "$firstname $lastname"
        GivenName = $firstname
        Surname = $lastname
        UserPrincipalName = $UsrPrincipalName
        SamAccountName = $loginname
        Path = $OuPath
        ScriptPath = $LoginScript
        AccountPassword = $securepassword
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
        Department = $Department
        DisplayName = $displayname
        Description = $Description
        Title = $jobtitle
        Enabled = $true
    }

    #Editors comment: Make a hashtable and use splatting when specifying lots of parameters
    $newcreatedusers = New-ADUser @vars -PassThru

    #starting a loop for adding the users to the groups
    Write-Host "`n"
    Write-Host "The account for $firstname $lastname created in $OuPath successfully"

}


$filepath = $Adgroups

foreach ($group in $Adgroups){

    $adgroup = $group.Groups.splite(',')

    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $group.Groups -members $SamAccountName

}
```

the CSV file:
[image: CSV Sample]

Comment: Where do the group names come from? A text file? A CSV file?

Comment: i've added a column in the CSV file, in each row, with comma separated

header "groups"
hr,notepad,terminal server users,NY branch

Comment: it's the same CSV file $path

Comment: Still unclear. What is `$Adgroups` in your script? It's never defined. You've added the group-loop outside the user-loop, which means `$SamAccountName` doesn't exist (which it doesn't either way, because you called it `$loginname` inside the loop). Add a sample of the csv for the groups and make sure the code in the question is complete..

Comment: i've added the csv file sample,
`$adgroups` is the variable for the groups header in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

after a long "play around" this is the code which creates new users and add them  to multiple groups from a CSV file:

```
cls
#get the csv file
$filepath = import-csv "C:\users.csv"

#set the variable for the uers
$newusers = $filepath

#set Passwords for new users 

$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "blahblah" -AsPlainText -Force

#start the loop for adding users

foreach ($user in $newusers) {


#Get user information

$firstname = $user.'First Name'.Trim()
$lastname = $user.'Last Name'.Trim()

#The "SamAccountName" is for the Pre windows 2000 login name has to be less than 20 characters
$loginname= $user.SamAccountName

#The "UserPrincipalname" is the regular login username
$UsrPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName

$jobtitle = $user.'Job Title'
$Department= $user.Department
$Description = $user.Description
$OuPath= $user.Path
$LoginScript=$user.ScriptPath
$displayname= $user.DisplayName

#Get Groups information
$group1 = $user.Group1
$group2 = $user.Group2
$group3 = $user.Group3
$group4 = $user.Group4    

#Creat the users in active directory

New-ADUser -Name "$firstname $lastname" -GivenName $firstname `
 `
 -Surname $lastname  -UserPrincipalName $UsrPrincipalName `
 `
 -SamAccountName $loginname -Path $OuPath -ScriptPath $LoginScript  `
 `
 -AccountPassword $securepassword -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false  `
 `
 -Department $Department -DisplayName $displayname `
 `
 -Description $Description -Title $jobtitle  -Enabled $true  



 #Add the users in to Groups

 Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.SamAccountName -MemberOf $user.group1
 Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.SamAccountName -MemberOf $user.group2
 Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.SamAccountName -MemberOf $user.group3
 Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.SamAccountName -MemberOf $user.group4



Write-Host "`n"
Write-Host "The account for $firstname $lastname created in $OuPath successfully"

}
```